# How to change constraint in ms sql if other bit column is true

Tags: sql-server

I'm building a codebook in database.
There I have three columns:

`[IDReal] int identity (1,1), [IsReal] bit not null, [Code] nvarchar (20) null`

Now I have somehow get that when user change [IsReal] to 1, that my column [Code] change to not null and unique and vice versa.

I was trying something like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sReal](
[IDReal] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Code] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[IsReal] [bit] NOT NULL,

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sReal] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DEF_IsReal]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsReal]
    GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sReal] ADD  CONSTRAINT [CHNG_IsReal] IF [IsReal]=1 THEN (ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sReal] ALTER COLUMN [Code] [nvarchar](20) not null unique) 
ELSE END IF
GO`
```

This, of course, is not working and I can't use triggers or functions or procedures to solve that.

Is there any other solution for accomplishing what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot solve this problem by dynamically changing the schema. The schema applies to the entire table. Instead, I believe you should add the following:

1. A filtered unique index to ensure unique values of Code only when IsReal has value 1:

   `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_code ON dbo.sReal (Code) WHERE IsReal = 1`
2. A check constraint that ensures that Code is never Null when IsReal is 1

   `ALTER TABLE dbo.sReal ADD CONSTRAINT cc_Code CHECK (IsReal = 0 OR Code IS NOT NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

This may helps you Try once Else Try in another way

```
IF EXISTS(

SELECT 1 From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='sReal'
AND COLUMN_NAME='IsReal' AND DATA_TYPE='bit'
)
Begin
DECLARE @Real BIT
SELECT TOP 1@Real=[IsReal] From [sReal] WHERE  [IsReal]=1

IF (@Real=1 )
Begin

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sReal] ALTER COLUMN [Code] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sReal] ADD CONSTRAINT UC_Code UNIQUE ([Code]);
END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way can be :

```
Declare @Variable1 int;
SELECT @Variable1 = [IsReal] From [sReal] WHERE  [IsReal]=1  --your user specific condition

IF @Variable1 = 1
BEGIN
    alter table [sReal] ALTER COLUMN [Code][nvarchar](20) NOT NULL
    alter table [sReal] ADD  CONSTRAINT [CHNG_IsReal] UNIQUE([Code])
END
ELSE 
IF @Variable1 <> 1  
BEGIN
    alter table [sReal] DROP  CONSTRAINT [CHNG_IsReal]
    alter table [sReal] ALTER COLUMN [Code][nvarchar](20) NULL
END
```